# npm install from a BASH script does not work correctly

Tags: bash, npm

I wrote a simple script that is invoked with GIT PUSH DEPLOY via ssh on a production server that I report below.

The problem is that the npm install command apparently produces a problem on a module (sharp) that is not installed.

If I do the same thing via ssh terminal I have no problem.

is there something I need to know about when to invoke npm install inside a bash script?

```
 1 #!/bin/bash
 2
 3 
 4 WWW="/opt/sites/strapi"
 5 
 6 TMP="/srv/tmp/strapi"
 7 
 8 REPO="/srv/git/strapi.git"
 9
10 ENV="/srv/tmp/strapi.env"
11 
12 mkdir -p $TMP
13 mkdir -p $ENV
14
15 cp $WWW/.env $ENV/
16
17 git --work-tree=$TMP --git-dir=$REPO checkout -f
18
19 cp $ENV/.env $TMP/
20 cd $TMP
21 npm install
22 NODE_ENV=production npm run build
23
24 cd /
25 rm -rf $WWW
26 mv $TMP $WWW
```

Comment: Please do not add line numbers when pasting code here; it means folks can't run it through syntax checkers, execute it themselves in a sandbox, etc.

Comment: That said, it would be helpful for purposes of this immediate problem to try to build a reproducer complete enough to reproduce your real problem when run without changes. That's not the case here now, because nobody else will have `/opt/sites/strapi` or your `/srv` directory hierarchy and its contents.

Comment: ...also, note that `ENV` in all-caps has a special meaning you probably don't want (if a copy of `sh` is started by a subprocess, it will try to run the contents of any file named by `ENV` on startup; even though you aren't explicitly exporting your own `ENV` here, if a parent process exported one, the new value will automatically override the environment copy of the old one). Use lower-case names for your own variables so they don't override names that modify shell or system-tool behavior.

Comment: sorry for line numbers, is my first question on stackoverflow

Comment: ...POSIX explicitly reserves names with at least one lower-case character for application use; see the relevant standards document at https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html. Other than that, as a matter of good practice you should quote your variable names (`mkdir -p "$TMP" "$ENV"`) -- though the values you're hardcoding won't have bad behavior when unquoted with the default value of `IFS`, that could change if different values are used later.

Comment: Also, it would be helpful to actually include the specific error messages you get in the question, instead of just describing it; _doubly_ so since the code given is not something someone can just run on their own to see the error themselves.